# Gradle Build failure due to requesting files from http maven site not https

Tags: gradle, maven-central

I am trying to use gradle to decompile forge (for some minecraft modding), when Building though it requests files from `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`, but since Jan 2020 the download section has switched to `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2`. Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the https URL instead of the http one?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use an old Gradle version and your build configuration has `mavenCentral()` as one of its repositories? In that case you can replace `mavenCentral()` with the following:

```
maven {
    url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
}
```